# How to add parenthesis to a string in python

Tags: python, pandas, string, replace, parentheses

I have a string and I would like to convert to a list or string with parenthesis. How do I do that?

The string is `st =  ((22027.0 22943.0, 22026.0 22939.0, 22025.0 22936.0, 22025.0 22932.0, 22027.0 22929.0, 22030.0 22926.0, 22031.0 22922.0, 22033.0 22919.0, 22033.0 22907.0, 22030.0 22908.0, 22029.0 22911.0))` The desired output should be of the following:

```
([(22027.0, 22943.0), (22026.0, 22939.0), (22025.0, 22936.0), (22025.0, 22932.0), (22027.0, 22929.0), (22030.0, 22926.0), (22031.0, 22922.0), (22033.0, 22919.0), (22033.0, 22907.0), (22030.0 ,22908.0), (22029.0, 22911.0)])
```

What I tried so far?

```
s = str('((22027.0 22943.0, 22026.0 22939.0, 22025.0 22936.0, 22025.0 22932.0, 22027.0 22929.0, 22030.0 22926.0, 22031.0 22922.0, 22033.0 22919.0, 22033.0 22907.0, 22030.0 22908.0, 22029.0 22911.0))')
op = s.replace(', ', '),(')
```

This does not give the desired output. How do I get the following output?

```
([(22027.0, 22943.0), (22026.0, 22939.0), (22025.0, 22936.0), (22025.0, 22932.0), (22027.0, 22929.0), (22030.0, 22926.0), (22031.0, 22922.0), (22033.0, 22919.0), (22033.0, 22907.0), (22030.0 ,22908.0), (22029.0, 22911.0)])
```

Comment: ```[tuple(map(float, pair.split())) for pair in s.strip("()").split(", ")]```

Comment: first getting rid of parens at either end, then split over `, `. Split again the resultant pairs and cast to float each and tuple the pair at the end.

Comment: the very enclosing pair of `( )` in your desired output does not define a new structure in Python, by the way. So it is the same without those parens.

Answer (score 0):

It's easier once you remove the enclosing parentheses.

From there, you can split on the comma and forming tuples from the paired strings (after you convert them to floats)

One commenter had a nice one-liner, but here is a for loop:

```
st =  "((22027.0 22943.0, 22026.0 22939.0, 22025.0 22936.0, 22025.0 22932.0, 22027.0 22929.0, 22030.0 22926.0, 22031.0 22922.0, 22033.0 22919.0, 22033.0 22907.0, 22030.0 22908.0, 22029.0 22911.0))"
st = [x.strip() for x in st[2:-2].split(",")]
res = []
for x in st:
    res.append(tuple(float(y) for y in x.split()))
print(res)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the result as a list of strings, you can combine `replace`, `lambda` and `map`

```py
list(map(lambda x: f'({x.strip().replace(" ", ",")})', st[2:-2].split(',')))

#output: ['(22027.0,22943.0)', '(22026.0,22939.0)', '(22025.0,22936.0)', '(22025.0,22932.0)', '(22027.0,22929.0)', '(22030.0,22926.0)', '(22031.0,22922.0)', '(22033.0,22919.0)', '(22033.0,22907.0)', '(22030.0,22908.0)', '(22029.0,22911.0)']
```

If you want the result as a list of tuples with float values, you can use `eval` on top of above method:

```py
list(map(lambda x: eval(f'({x.strip().replace(" ", ",")})'), st[2:-2].split(',')))

#output: [(22027.0, 22943.0), (22026.0, 22939.0), (22025.0, 22936.0), (22025.0, 22932.0), (22027.0, 22929.0), (22030.0, 22926.0), (22031.0, 22922.0), (22033.0, 22919.0), (22033.0, 22907.0), (22030.0, 22908.0), (22029.0, 22911.0)]
```

Answer (score 0):

- Strip off the leading and trailing parentheses.
- Split the resulting string at `,`.
- Now convert every `string` to `float` and create a `tuple`.
- Append those `tuples` to list.

```
st =  "((22027.0 22943.0, 22026.0 22939.0, 22025.0 22936.0, 22025.0 22932.0, 22027.0 22929.0, 22030.0 22926.0, 22031.0 22922.0, 22033.0 22919.0, 22033.0 22907.0, 22030.0 22908.0, 22029.0 22911.0))"
st = st[2:-2]
s = st.split(',')

res = []

for i in s:
    res.append(tuple(map(float, i.split())))
```